# Zoom and Panning ImageView Android oncreate call

Tags: android, android-layout, oncreate

I know its a bit old post but any help would be very appreciated. I tried to call this class"MyImageView" here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   tools:context=".MainScreen" >
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:contentDescription="@string/map"
       android:scaleType="matrix"
       android:src="@drawable/map" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainscreen);

    final ImageView imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Resources resource = this.getResources();
    XmlPullParser parser = resource.getXml(R.layout.activity_mainscreen);
    AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);

    final MyImageView miv = new MyImageView(this, attributes);

    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
           return miv.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });

}
```

here is the link the originale post:

[Zoom and Panning ImageView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169905/zoom-and-panning-imageview-android/21725090#21725090)

and there is no zoom or pan, please I'm still new to this so pardon my ignorant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an pan and zoom listener.

Follow this code.

remove the imageView.setOnTouchListener from your code.

and add my code

```
final ImageView imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

imageView.setOnTouchListener(new Touch()); 

Bitmap map=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map);

imageView.setImageBitmap(map);
```

Now create a new class in your project and name it "Touch"

write the following in the touch class

```
package com.forlo.photo;

import android.graphics.Matrix;  
import android.graphics.PointF;  
import android.util.FloatMath;  
import android.view.MotionEvent;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;  
import android.widget.ImageView; 

public class Touch implements OnTouchListener {  

 // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image  
public static Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  
public static Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();  

 // We can be in one of these 3 states  
 static final int NONE = 0;  
 static final int DRAG = 1;  
 static final int ZOOM = 2;  
 int mode = NONE;  

 // Remember some things for zooming  
 PointF start = new PointF();  
 PointF mid = new PointF();  
 float oldDist = 1f;  


 @Override  
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  
  ImageView view = (ImageView) v;  
  // Dump touch event to log  
  dumpEvent(event);  

  // Handle touch events here...  
  switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {  
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
   savedMatrix.set(matrix);  
   start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());  
   mode = DRAG;  
   break;  
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:  
   oldDist = spacing(event);  
   if (oldDist > 10f) {  
    savedMatrix.set(matrix);  
    midPoint(mid, event);  
    mode = ZOOM;  
   }  
   break;  
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:  
   mode = NONE;  
   break;  
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  
   if (mode == DRAG) {  
    // ...      
    matrix.set(savedMatrix);  
    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);      
   } else if (mode == ZOOM) {  
    float newDist = spacing(event);  
    if (newDist > 10f) {  
     matrix.set(savedMatrix);  
     float scale = newDist / oldDist;  
     matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);  
    }  
   }  
   break;  
  }  

  view.setImageMatrix(matrix);  
  return true; // indicate event was handled  
 }  

 /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */  
 private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {  
  String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",  
    "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };  
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
  int action = event.getAction();  
  int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;  
  sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);  
  if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN  
    || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {  
   sb.append("(pid ").append(  
     action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);  
   sb.append(")");  
  }  
  sb.append("[");  
  for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {  
   sb.append("#").append(i);  
   sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));  
   sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));  
   sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));  
   if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())  
    sb.append(";");  
  }  
  sb.append("]");  
 }  

 /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */  
 private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {  
  float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);  
  float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);  
  return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);  
 }  

 /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */  
 private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {  
  float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);  
  float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);  
  point.set(x / 2, y / 2);  
 }  
}
```

and change your layout to this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainScreen" >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:contentDescription="@string/map"
   android:scaleType="matrix"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now tell me if pan and zoom worked..

Comment: thank you for you quick respond, I made the class as you said and the call in the main activity doesnt seam to work. I used  `imageView.setOnTouchListener(new Touch());` in the main activity

Comment: did you give a bitmap to imageview. Imageview pan and zoom works if you give a Bitmap to it using.    imageview.setImageBitmap(yourbitmap);

Comment: Hello @sandeep thank you for your clarification, it work fine the issue is that its a endless zoom in/out, I was digging a bit more and found a class very similar to yours with zoom limit, so the issue now is that I wana have click and long click on the same imageview but only the ontuch method works here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740483/pan-zoom-click-and-long-click-in-one-imageview

Comment: Well the good news is that with your class I was able to use the click and longclick by returning false in the OnTouch "indicate event was handled", the bad news is that everytime I zoom or pan it is counted as click or long click so I removed the click function but I still get the longclick toast everytime I zoom or pan is there a way to change or override the longclick time??

Comment: imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "long click", TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND).show();
       Log.i("onClick", "logclick");       
       return false;
      }
  });

Comment: how Can I add boundaries to the zoom in and out in your class?