# Zoom and drag image?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I followed this tutorial to make image slider with swipe and pinch, zoom gestures. I followed [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/) tutorial and the whole code is [Here](https://github.com/androidhive/Android-Fullscreen-Image-Slider-with-Swipe-and-Pinch-Zoom-Gestures). But I have noticed one problem in it.

When you zoom-in image, and then drag it, it is cropped to the edge of the screen so drag right leads to next image instead of moving to the right part of same image. I will be thankful if someone helps me. Here is my code for image touch

TouchImageView.java

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix;

static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

int viewWidth, viewHeight;

static final int CLICK = 3;

float saveScale = 1f;

protected float origWidth, origHeight;

int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {

    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;

    // Creates a ScaleGestureDetector with the supplied listener.
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    matrix = new Matrix();

    m = new float[9];

    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {

            // A pressed gesture has started, the motion contains the
            // initial starting location.
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                last.set(curr);
                start.set(last);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if (mode == DRAG) {

                    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;

                    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;

                    float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                            origWidth * saveScale);

                    float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                            origHeight * saveScale);

                    matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);

                    fixTrans();

                    last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                mode = NONE;

                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);

                if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)

                    performClick();

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            }
            setImageMatrix(matrix);

            invalidate();

            return true;
        }
    });
}

// Set the value for maximum zoom
public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();

        float origScale = saveScale;

        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;

        if (saveScale > maxScale) {

            saveScale = maxScale;

            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;

        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {

            saveScale = minScale;

            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)

            // Postconcats the matrix with the specified scale.
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                    viewHeight / 2);

        else
            // Postconcats the matrix with the specified scale.
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

        fixTrans();

        return true;
    }
}

void fixTrans() {

    matrix.getValues(m);

    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];

    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
            * saveScale);

    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}

float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    float minTrans, maxTrans;

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }

    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;
}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;
    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {

        float scale;

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;

        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;

        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;

        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center the image
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;

        setImageMatrix(matrix);
       }
       fixTrans();
    }
}
```

Comment: look into this [post.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7458910/3326331) or [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12184210/3326331)

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrisbanes's photoview: 
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

It has zoom and touch gestures.